# Merging remote branches in git

Tags: git, git-remote

I am developing a system where I'm following the trails of another project, adding my own stuff but not directly to the original project. I setup my repository with three remote branches:

1. Master - Where my development takes place.
2. Vendor - Where I sync with the original project periodically.
3. Integration - Where I want to merge (Master) and (Vendor) together.

My workflow idea is for the synchronization to take place automatically (since it's basically a fast-forward of sorts), and the integration to be half-manual (since it requires merges and fixes). I've got the first part (the sync) covered, but I can't figure out what command/s to actually issue to integrate Master and Vendor into integration.

This is the output of *git branch -a*:

```
* integration
  master
  vendor
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/integration
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/vendor
```

How do I go forward from this point to:

1. Synchronize this workspace with the remote repository?
2. Merge vendor & master into integration?
3. Push integration back to the remote repository?

And obviously, if I have something wrong in the workflow I'd love to hear it.

Comment: The integration branch is not necessary, the vendor branch already have the code from Vendor and Master. Note that every branch is actually a reference, (pointer in c++), it is referencing the commit point. In that case, the vender branch already is what you need in Integration branch

Comment: The Vendor in that case does not have the code from Master. Think of it as two parallel projects where A (my project) needs the updates of B (the other project) but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `integration` branch is not strictly necessary (you could integrate directly `vendor` into `master`, by rebasing `master` on top of `vendor`), it can be useful.

Integrating a branch `A` in a branch `B` can be done by:

- merging `A` in `B` (but that means any current development you have in `B` is "on hold" pending the resolutions of any merge conflict, and the re-runs of all the tests)
- rebasing `B` on top of `A` (`git rebase A`), but that would change `B`'s history.

I would rebase `integration` on top of `Vendor`, solving any conflict there, and then merge `integration` in `master`, keeping `master` history linear.

Comment: I want to continuously integrate vendor and master but without interfering the current progress on master (the mentioned integration is possibly lengthy), that's why I need the Integration branch. Rebasing Integration on Vendor is a good idea indeed. What I'm missing are the actual commands needed to do the merge since what I tried in the past didn't really work.

Comment: @EldadMor `git checkout Integration; git rebase Vendor; git checkout master; git merge Integration` should be enough. That supposes you don't push `Integration` to a public repo, which allows you to rebase it as often as you need.

Comment: I think that's what I tried; I'll retry and get back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: @EldadMor: if you're doing as VonC suggests, and just rebasing onto `vendor`, you don't need to create that local branch (`vendor`) - you can just use the remote-tracking branch that's updated when you do `git fetch <upstream-repository-remote>`

Comment: @MarkLongair - If I understand you correctly, that would work if I update from git; however the vendor' project is not using git :-)

Comment: @EldadMor: ah, OK - that wasn't clear to me from the question.

Comment: @MarkLongair - yep, that's because it wasn't mentioned :-) In this case I have the branches setup and I really like the way they are right now for various reasons, I just can't seem to merge them successfully.